# Unable to setup website because of .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hey guys I am facing this bad yet confusing 500 error.
I searched on the net about it and came to know it is cuz of .htaccess.

The internet as well as myself know there is something about Rewrite but I am unable to figure the simple mistake out.

Kindly help guys.

Here is the .htaccess details

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Please use "www.website.com" to explain in a simple manner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the `AcceptPathInfo` since if it's disabled then you get looping.

Comment: Also please check your Apache error logs.